# How to calculate the passed time and return it descriptively?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to know the passed time in between two dates, for example:  `date1` and `date2`, I'd need a function like  `getPassedTime(date1, date2)`.

The function result should be a string like `'1 day 3 hours 12 minutes 10 seconds'` or just `'40 seconds'`.

I know that the method `timeIntervalSinceDate` of the class `NSDate` can be used, but the problem is converting it to a detailed/descriptive string that could easily be understood.

Can anyone help? Sharing some code or tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/components:fromDate:toDate:options:):

```
- (NSDateComponents *)components:(NSUInteger)unitFlags fromDate:(NSDate *)startingDate toDate:(NSDate *)resultDate options:(NSUInteger)opts;
```

You will still have to decide which components to display, but they will be broken out by unit.